# sklearn: Need to reshape array but don't know where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I've tried almost everything, I know there is a way or something that I'm missing, I'm really noob in ML but I would really appreciate any help or explanations.

`df["Date"] and df["Open"] are arrays like: [1,2, ..., 10]`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv('AAPL.csv')
clf = LinearRegression()

i = 0
for date in df["Date"]:
    s = date
    s = s.replace("-","")
    df["Date"][i] = s

    i += 1

clf.fit(df["Date"],df["Open"])
print("Prediction:", clf.predict(df["Date"][-1]))
```

Here is the error that Python throws me:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[19801212. 19801215. 19801216. ... 20191127. 20191129. 20191202.].

Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single
feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample. line 16
```

After some trys, errors and googling i figured out how to reshape df["Date] by doing this:
`clf.fit(np.array(df["Date"]).reshape(-1,1),df["Open"])`

But now throws me this:
`ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

I really appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: `df['Date']` looks like string valued. I don't think that's good for LinearRegression.

Comment: double square brackets not single clf.fit(df[["Date"]],df[["Open"]])

Comment: double square: ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reshaping:

```
clf.fit(df["Date"].values.reshape(-1,1),df["Open"].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

But not sure you have correct `datetime` type column for `df["Date"]` since `pandas` could read it as a string. You could do:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_numeric(pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]))
```

for type conversion (integer at last). Lastly, if you have `nan` rows, you could eliminate them with:

```
df = df.dropna(how='any',axis=0, subset=['Date','Open'])
```

Hope this works.

Comment: I think that scikitlearn allows for dataframes so clf.fit(df[['date']],df[['Open']]) should also work

Comment: @Ryan only double bracket on `x`: `clf.fit(df[['date']],df['Open'])`.